# Visual Studio Code add Launch on Android Emulator

Tags: android, visual-studio-code

I want to run my code on an Android Emulator in Visual Studio Code.

In my launch.json file is only "launch on Android". I know that I have to setup "launch on Android Emulator" but the thing is I saw other people install the Nativescript extension and in their Version it already was included.

See [here](https://youtu.be/KQHJewS3tqA?t=49).

What I did:

- Installed the NativeScript Extension
- Installed Android SDK
- Setup of an Android device

I think that I have an Android device but I cant run it and I dont know how to integrate it into my launch.json or run it (see picture).

[image: Android devices]